# extjs 4.x with Sencha Architect v2.x

Tags: extjs, extjs-mvc, extjs4.1, sencha-architect

We are trying to evaluate extjs 4.x with Sencha Architect v2.x (UI designer) for our in-house sales tracking system. We are able to design and develop each/single modules like user manager, item manager etc as an application for using designer.

However, in order to make entire application work - driven by menu or dashboard and opening each module/application in separate tab, we are not able to make out the appropriate approach. Are we expected to design entire application in single design file which I believe is not practical as we would have more than 50 modules and many UIs.

We want to have something like we have dashboard with tree menu on left and tabs opening on right. On menu click we create a tab (if it does not already added) and open application that was originally designed with designer. E.g. if user clicks on “Sales order” we open sales order tab and so on.

We wanted make sure that we do use designer with model, store. I would appreciate suggestion on reusability of components like models, stores etc.
Ref: http://blog.dnet-ebusiness-suite.com/2012/04/sales-order-to-invoice-and-delivery.html

Comment: So, basically, you want to create standalone ExtJS4 modules that can act as applications independently, or as a "module" inside an application. Are they (each) going to be more complicated than a controller with a list and form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Architect 2 does not have a single design file.  In fact each class has it's own file.  You would not need to have separate projects.  In fact both the metadata and the source Architect produces is very source control friendly.